# Unable to bind the WPF ChartPlotter to the View using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dynamic-data-display

I just followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441575/dynamic-data-display-with-observablecollection) to create a simple Chart Plotter using MVVM. But I am unable to bind the data-source [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmx3r.png).

XAML

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GrayPlotter"
    xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0" x:Class="GrayPlotter.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="117*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="192*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="143*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="58*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <d3:ChartPlotter x:Name="chartplot" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="168" Margin="43,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="379">
        <d3:LineGraph DataSource="{Binding Plotvalue}"></d3:LineGraph>
    </d3:ChartPlotter>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace GrayPlotter.ViewModel
{
class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    ChartPlotter Plotvaluetemp = new ChartPlotter();

    ChartPlotter plotvalue = null;
    public ChartPlotter Plotvalue
    {
        get { return plotvalue; }
        set
        {
            plotvalue = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Plotvalue");
        }
    }

    class plotData
    {
        public ObservableDataSource<Point> Data { get; set; }

        public plotData()
        {
            Data = new ObservableDataSource<Point>();
        }
    }

    plotData plotDatavalue = new plotData();

    public void UpdateplotInformation()
    {
        double[] my_array = new double[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < my_array.Length; i++)
        {
            my_array[i] = Math.Sin(i);
            plotDatavalue.Data.Collection.Add(new Point(i, my_array[i]));
        }
        Plotvaluetemp.AddLineGraph(plotDatavalue.Data);         
        Plotvalue = Plotvaluetemp;        
    }
}
}
```

And Mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace GrayPlotter
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainWindowViewModel viewModel ;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();        
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        viewModel.UpdateplotInformation();
    }
}
}
```

I am just near but what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your xaml =>

```
DataSource="{Binding Data}"
```

And your back to =>

```
private ObservableDataSource<Point> data;

    public ObservableDataSource<Point> Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            data = value;
            RaisPropertyChangedEvent("Data");
        }
    }

    public void UpdateplotInformation()
    {
        var list = new List<Point>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Point(i, Math.Sin(i)));
        }
        Data = new ObservableDataSource<Point>(list);
    }
```

Comment: `@Shakra` I tied the same with `CompositeDataSource` instead of `Point` but failed to display results.