# Display Chartplotter using MVVM with CompositeDataSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, plot, dynamic-data-display

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756564/unable-to-bind-the-wpf-chartplotter-to-the-view-using-mvvm) link to bind data to view .But I am unable to display results using CompositeDataSource uisng MVVM.

```
pixelX = new double[grayScaleData.Length];
grayLevelY = new double[grayScaleData.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < grayScaleData.Length; i++)
{
    pixelX[i] = i;
    grayLevelY[i] = grayScaleData[i];
    if (i >= (leftEdge + avgGrayoffset) && i <= (rightEdge - avgGrayoffset))
    {
        totalGrayScale += grayScaleData[i];
        totalPixels++;
    }
}

EnumerableDataSource<double> xSrc = new EnumerableDataSource<double>(pixelX);
xSrc.SetXMapping(x => x);
grayScaleDataSource = new EnumerableDataSource<double>(grayLevelY);
grayScaleDataSource.SetYMapping(y => y);
CompositeDataSource source= new CompositeDataSource(xSrc, grayScaleDataSource);

for (int i = 0; i < grayScaleData.Length; i++)
{
    //here I am not able to convert a CompositeDataSource to a point source
    // list.Add(new Point(??,??));
}
GrayScalePlotData = new ObservableDataSource<Point>(list);
```

using just a `Point` I am able to see some random plot

```
list.Add(new Point(pixelX[i], grayLevelY[i]));
```

can anyone suggest what is the better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the `CompositeDataSource` to a binding variable did the trick.